# WinAPI : How to force DATETIMEPICK to use standard calender rather than local calendar settings

Tags: c++, winapi

It seems DATETIMEPICK control (in Win32 API) uses calendar settings in "Region and Language" settings under control panel. In my case, it shows Buddhist calendar where year 2015 will be shown as year 2558.

Is there any flags or settings that can help me to force a specific DATETIMEPICK control to use another calendar instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the Date Time Picker always uses the calendar returned by `GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, ...)` - it doesn't provide a way to specify an arbitrary calendar.